# Dealing with a changing Excel table structure to import to a database table

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql, generics, sql-server-2012

I'm looking for a strategy to deal with the following Excel to db-issue (SQL Server 2012):

The input will be Excel files of the same subject but the column setup in those Excel files might change from month to month, meaning columns will be removed or added inside these Excel files, which isn't the "greatest" scenario for maintaining a db-table structure.

Note that when a Excel file is changed, the Filename/ID is also changed.

So, to store those files (via **SSIS**) in **one single db-table** I would set up a "**generic**" structure using column names COL1 to COLn. I then would add a **version** field to each Excel file so that I could create some sort of **mapping table** where I define the proper column names depending on the version. Basically a new month will create a new version number. This should then help me create a view to extract all versions with the appropriate column names.

In the first version I have about 120 columns to deal with.

I also have a "**crosstable**-scenario" because some columns contain year values.
For example let's say that the input file contains Savings 2009, Savings 2010, Savings 2011 columns. If, in version 2, the Savings 2012 column is added, I would need to create another column in the db-table unless "Savings 2009" is removed and I added the values for 2010 to the "2009 column".

You see it is a mess!

With this structure I will always have to change the import workflow and adjust the name mapping but I cannot think of a better way to deal with this problem.

Do I need to split up the columns to different tables?

I hope my problem came across and that you can guide me to a clean, "worry-free" solution :-)

As you might have guessed I don't have much influence on the input files I need to deal with.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I face this problem a lot.  Often, business users often prefer dealing with Excel files.  And that information is needed in databases.  The following is my strategy.

First, I have a stored procedure that reads an Excel table.  This stored procedure reads the headers from one row and the data starting at another row.  It assigns the headers as column names and the formats as the database type for the column.

Second, I keep the previous version of the table.  If a column has disappeared or changed type, then I generate an email to notify of the problem.  Usually, the new version is the correct version, and I just accept it as the correct table.  This provides a feedback loop.

This solution allows the users to control their files.  It also guarantees that queries running on the tables will work on the new data, because the column names and data types remain the same.