# Script to import ever changing Excel CSV file into SQL Server Express 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, csv

I have looked at this site and several other, and the closest I could come to was [Dealing with a changing Excel table structure to import to a database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121948/dealing-with-a-changing-excel-table-structure-to-import-to-a-database-table)
But I'm actually looking for the script to identify the Column Name and Type from the CSV file, and to create the Table from that.

The actual Importing script is working well, but it only caters for fixed Headers, while I have headers varying between 160 and 170 during any given time.

Comment: what tool are you using? SSIS or just diect import from SQL SERVER ??

Comment: Hi, I'm using SQL Server Management Studio, not tools, directly into SQL.

Comment: look there is now even in ssis, to do this, better would be a if you just dump the file in the  database in a table having one column, once this data is in database you can do anything and everything on this

Comment: Is SSIS available for free download? Cant seem to find it?

Comment: Trial version 2 months with SQL SERVER! you have ssms ?? if yes it must be already installed.

Comment: I've got SSMS installed, found it now! But not available with Express?

Comment: Its with all the versions and with specific version are us using ?Do you know basic SSIS ? If yes.. then go for file type checking in it and load the data in data base, once in data base write SP like stuff to change this to your desired table (final table )

Comment: Only got 2 options available with SSIS: Data Profile Viewer (which states I need at least Standard SQL) and Execute Package Utility (unable to do anything, as everything is greyed out)

Comment: did you see anything  like "SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio" THIS is where you will be able to SEE ssis packages.

Comment: Not at all unfortunately. BIDS is not visible. Available for free?

Comment: Try installing SQL server Again? in any other drive and see in steps if you have excluded this in previous installation.

Comment: I'll only be able to this a bit later, thanks! However, I dont recall having seen it as an option?

Comment: Welcome, Try downloading from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6362. If you need any further help once you install SSIS msg me.